# 2FA with Nuxt auth module

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, google-2fa

Please I'm not able to wrap my head around how I can extent the Nuxt auth module to implement 2FA like google authenticator or sms and phone authentication. I would really appreciate a code example as well. thank you.

I have only been able to implement the local strategy

Comment: Did you find a solution?